# Can't get appbarTogglebutton to display as checked in Template 10's PageHeader

Tags: uwp-xaml, template10

I can't seem to get the AppBarToggleButton to act like a toggle button when used inside Template 10's PageHeader. To simplify, I created a new project using the Hamburger template in Template 10.
I added the following code that binds the toggle button's "IsChecked" to the Viewmodel's bool "Settings":

```
    <!--  primary commands in XAML -->
    <controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Setting" Label="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding Settings, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    </controls:PageHeader.PrimaryCommands>

    // ViewModel code
    bool _Settings = false;
    public bool Settings { get { return _Settings; } set { Set(ref _Settings, value); } }
```

I used several methods to change the ViewModel value to "true", but it had no effect on the Toggles appearance. I even tried setting IsChecked to checked (no binding) in the designer. The toggle is still not highlighting as checked. This has to be something really stupid on my part, but I grepped through the template 10 samples not finding any uses of AppBarTogglebutton in the PageHeader --surprising me. So, once again I'm baffled by something that should be so simple. Maybe I need to do this using a Style, hope not. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the choice of colors Template 10 uses for it's default "PageHeader" background matches the default highlight color used for selected state in "AppBarToggleButton" making it appear not to be selected. The easy solution is to change the background color of "PageHeader" so it doesn't match the highlight color used for the AppBarToggleButton.